# PHP, is it posible to have form1 inside form2, and action form1 not refresh the form2

Tags: php, html

this is simple multi select form which select users and pass to input **users**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input name='input1' type='text'/>
    <input name='input2' type='text'/>
    <input name='input3' type='text'/>
    <select name="user[]" multiple="multiple" ondblclick="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="1">user1</option>
        <option value="2">user2</option>
        <option value="3">user3</option>
    </select>
    <input  type="text" name='selectedusers' value="<?php
      if (isset($_POST['user'])){
        $con = $_POST['user'];
        foreach($con as $user_single)
            echo '-'.$user_single; }
        ?> "/>
    <input type="Submit" value="abc" name="abc" />
</form>
```

now here the idea is to keep the input1, 2 and 3 which was input lastly, and make select.
but here if i use multi select the previous input gets blank.

How i can keep the previous input values and make multi select pass the selected value to input name **selectedusers** and submit form..

regards

Comment: Use AJAX http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP

Comment: here using multi select (mulit select values selects from database)

Comment: input1, 2 3 have no value to submit

Comment: here i will enter the value during form submitting

Comment: Html standards doesnt allow nested forms. You can use some JavaScript hacks to control your events but if your user have JavaSCript disabled the website will be unusable and it is not save that all browsers will behave same when you try to do that. I suggest to find another solution when building your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think HTML standards allow nesting of forms. I had once ran into the same scenario and i saw this in http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element .

> Content model: Flow content, but with no form element descendants.

i.e. html denies nesting of form elements. So, is it not possible to have form1 inside form2.

But you can use multiple submits inside the same form. and you can distinguish between the submits by the "name" and "value" attribute.

```
<form>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit 1" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit 2" />

</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']) and $_POST['submit']=="Submit 1")
{
...
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']) and $_POST['submit']=="Submit 2")
{
...
}

?>
```

Comment: here if i use this, in same page there is tow form if and i have entered value for every input in both but when i submit form 1 the values which belong to form2 gets clean and i have to enter values again

Comment: I cannot understand your problem clearly. Do you need to submit 2 forms at once? If you hav 2 forms in a page and if you submit one form, the page is reloaded and the values will be reset. So if you want to retain the values of form 2 during the submission of form 1, you have to submit form 2 along with form 1 using javascript. And after submission you may populate the values in form 2 from the $_POST array

Comment: i have tow form2, form1 and form2, form1 is inside the form2, here in form1 if i submit it it will pass values to inputs of form2, like my question up, if i enter value for some inputs of form2 then i submit form1 it will give result but it will clean all the inputs of the page so i want the action of from1 not to effect on any other input

Comment: just like tow input box drag and rop betten their values

Comment: First of all, Form_1 cannot be inside form_2 according to html standards. The 2 forms must be separate. Then,You can either use ajax for submitting your form_1 and putting the values into form_2  or you can submit the two forms at once and then use $_POST to populate your fields during page reload.

Answer (score -1):

What if you try with

```
extract($_POST);
```

in form submitted area.

and then assign values to form fields.

Let me know if its not clear.

Comment: please can you explain it little. regards

Comment: <?php
     extract($_POST);
    ?>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title;?>">
        <select onchange="this.form.submit()"></select>
    </form>

in this way, I am sure your old values will be still in form fields.